# Abstract class for IntArray and StringArray in kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

is there a class that both IntArray abd StringArray heritate from 
i have a function that will need as argument all sort of Arrays to use it in a fragmentadapter

```
class MyPagerAdapter(val fragmentManager: FragmentManager,val collection:Array):FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager){
override fun getCount(): Int {
    Log.i("viewpager","count"+fragmentManager.fragments.size.toString())

     return collection.size
    }
}
```

is it possible ? 
or would i use another way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle any `Array<T>` type, your class should probably be generic:

```
class MyPagerAdapter<T>(val fragmentManager: FragmentManager, val collection: Array<T>)
```

There is no common supertype for the primitive array wrappers, there are however [`toTypedArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) functions or each of them that can convert them to the appropriately typed generic array instance, for example:

```
val intArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val typedArray: Array<Int> = intArray.toTypedArray()
MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, typedArray)
```

Comment: Well elaborate.

Comment: that's why i need exactly

Answer (score 1):

If you only need `collection.size`, just pass the size.

If you need anything else, it can't be done generically and handle `IntArray` and other primitive arrays; you'll need to convert to `Array<T>` as in @zsmb13's answer.

Comment: i need all the content of the array , not just the size , so i think working with the generic class is the correct way